# htaccess 301 redirection: adding cakephp component & action as query string in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to apply 301 redirection on domain so that we can redirect our users to http://domain.com/page/about.

**htaccess:**

Redirect 301 Domain Domain/page/about

**Url adding continue page/about in URL**
http://domain.com/page/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/aboutpage/about

**Browser Error:**

Warning: glob() [function.glob]: Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters.

Please advice me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive links two path nodes, so when you start with `Redirect /path /something/something`, it redirects *every* URI that *starts* with `/path`. Which means a request like `http://domain/path/some/other/path` gets redirected to `/something/something/some/other/path`. So you can't use `Redirect` for what you're doing. You can try `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /page/about
```

Or, alternatively, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /page/about [L,R=301]
```